# Запас и опасность

Tags: морфемика

Однокоренные ли это слова?
Фасмер предполагает родственность. 
Но меня интересует, как это сейчас подают "в школе".

Хорошо бы ещё рабочую ссылку на морфемный (морфологический) словарь - скачать или онлайн. Устал по битым ссылкам ходить.

Все, нашел... Спасибо.

Запас/н/о́й и запа́с/н/ый.
Опа́с/н/ый.
(Тихонов)

http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/~%D0%97/65/

Не закрываю, может кому-то будет интересно.

Comment: Вообще интересный вопрос. 

А как же их, эти слова, тогда **по смыслу** связать?

Корень *пас* получается? Что же он значит? 

*О-пасный*. О- пожалуй, это что-то по окружности, вокруг...

Интересная загадка :-)

Answer (score 2):

В школе говорят, что это исторически родственные слова, как и Фасмер. Сейчас корни разные, а в праиндоевр. *pa - «содержать; кормить; пасти». Слово "пасти" первоначально означало "охранять, беречь", затем "присматривая, кормить"(спасти-избавить от опасности, пастбище - там, где кормят и присматривают за скотом), здесь значения пересекаются.

Запасной-от за+пасти-сделать запас-содержание, корм впрок.

Опасность от ОПАСНЫЙ .  В памятниках письменности отмечается с XI в. в форме опасьныи <охранительный,тщательный>. Впоследствии слаб. ь исчез, звук с отвердел. Знач., вероятно, развивалось следующим образом: <заботливый> > <предостерегающий> (ср. др.-рус. опас(ь)ная грамота <страховая бумага>), далее - <внушающий опасение, осторожность>, <грозящий опасностью> > <способный при- 
чинить несчастье>. Др.-рус. опасьныи образовано с пом. суф. относит, прил.
-ьн- от сущ. опасъ <охрана, защита> (ср. диал. опас, опаска <опасение>), 
производного от глаг. спасти (опасати) <оберегать, охранять>, <внушать 
осторожность>. Этот глаг. является производным с прист. о- от глаг. пасти 
сберечь, охранять> (ср. спасти). От глаг. спасти с пом. суф. -енщ-е обра- 
зовано сущ. опасение (или же от опасен с суф. -uj-e) <боязнь чего-либо>. 
На базе предложного сочетания без опаса посредством суф. -ьн- > соврем.
-н- образовано прил. безопасный <не грозящий опасностью>, <защищенный>. http://lib.co.ua/diction/cygank/cygank.txt

Так что современные значения разные, а первоначально, исторически одинаковые:запасной связан с запасом (от "пасти"), опасный - связан с опасом, опаской (от "пасти").

Comment: Да, Людмила, спасибо. Меня интересовал конкретный вопрос о том, как это формулируется в школе.
Я на одном форуме привел цитату, в которой утверждалось, что запаснОй и запАсный могли произойти от ***разных*** корней (запас и опасность).    
  
И был закидан банановыми шкурками. Не за саму идею, а за то, что кто-то посмел усомниться в том, что слова однокоренные - хоть с кокой-то тоски зрения.   
  
Шанский меня убедил, что остракизм подвергся я незаслуженно. А собственно этимологию я знаю по Фасмеру.